# UIActionSheet with UIPickerView showing nothing iPad

Tags: ipad, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerview inside a ActionSheet `dateSheet` that gets the demographic of the user. Here is my code.

```
    UIPickerView *picker=[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,125,320,216)];
    picker.tag = 1;
    picker.delegate=self;
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator=YES;
    [dateSheet addSubview:picker];
    [dateSheet showInView:self.view];
    [dateSheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0,220,320,312)];
```

I changed the code from this:

```
    UIPickerView *picker=[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,95,320,216)];
    picker.tag = 1;
    picker.delegate=self;
    picker.showsSelectionIndicator=YES;
    [dateSheet addSubview:picker];
    [dateSheet showInView:self.view];
    [dateSheet setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 168, 320, 312)];
```

But either way now on the iPad simulator it looks like this

[image]
Here is where I set my pickerviews data

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
   return [pickerdata objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

Comment: Did you just forget to set `dataSource`?

Comment: I have the same thing for iPhone as I do iPad. I set items in titleForRow method. Does iPad need the dataSource when iPhone doesn't? The code is above

Comment: How do you "put" the data in this UIPickerView?

Comment: With the above code, I set what I have in `pickerdata` to the title of the pickerView row. Again this works for iPhone but for iPad it doesn't. I believe it has something to do with my frame.